# PDF upload/view webapplication in PHP

Tags: php, web-applications, pdf

I want to create a web application where users can upload .pdf files which will be stored in mySQL database, and they can also view .pdfs stored in the database? 
about the upload part, it's pretty foreword, however the view part in a bit challenging, so anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: first of check any pdf reader is install in system or not because browser need pdf reader to read document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below for complete reference,

- http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1001_-pdf-files-upload-via-PHP-store-in-MySQL-retrieve.html
- http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

Follow all steps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [ResourceSpace](http://www.resourcespace.org): it's written in PHP and implements uploading, processing, storing and viewing of files in many formats, including pdf.

Comment: hey I need to write plugin for resourcespace. can you suggest where to start?